# Going back with my browser = wrong active class link

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress website, all pages are loaded with Ajax.js.
Everything is working, changing pages without loading all of the website, changing the url after click… 
but ONE problem remain : when I click on « go back » on my browser, the active class link is ALWAYS the first page name.
Where does that come from ?

Here is my a part of my code

```
    $(function(){

    $(window).bind('popstate', function() {

    var url = window.location;
    var hash = url.href.substring(url.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    $('#contenu').load( url + ' #contenu');

    $('#menu li').removeClass('active');

    if(hash.length == 0) {
        $('#menu li').first().addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#menu li.'+hash+'').addClass('active');
    }

});


    $('#loading').hide();


$('#menu a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#loading').slideDown();
    $('#menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    var lien = $(this).attr('href');

    $('#contenu').slideUp(500, function() {

        $('#contenu').load( lien + ' #contenu', function(){

            $('#contenu').slideDown(500, function(){

                $('#loading').slideUp();
        history.pushState(null, null, lien);
            });

        });


    }); }); });
```

And an image
[image: See here that the active class is always set on the homepage link -when I go back with the browser-]

Comment: Add a breakpoint, step through the code and check the content of the variables. And why don't you use [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash)?

Comment: Beginner, don't know about it ! hmm, when I place an alert after var url, the url does show up

Comment: can't seem to find